# Get records in Last 24 Hours having matching data and the maximum value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with below struture.

```
    CREATE TABLE  notifications (
    `notification_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `source` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `created_time` datetime NOT NULL,
    `not_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `not_content` longtext NOT NULL,
    `notifier_version` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `notification_reason` varchar(245) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`notification_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `notifications` (`notification_id`,`source`,`created_time`,`not_type`,`not_content`,`notifier_version`,`notification_reason`) VALUES 
    (50,'Asia','2018-05-01 18:10:12','Alert','You are alerted for some Reason','NO_03','Some Reason 1'),
    (51,'Asia','2018-04-29 14:10:12','Alert','You are alerted for some Reason','NO_02','Some Reason 8'),
    (52,'Europe','2018-04-29 10:10:12','Warning','You are Warned for som Reason','NO_02',NULL),
    (53,'Europe','2018-05-01 10:10:12','Warning','You are Warned for som Reason','NO_02',NULL),
    (54,'Europe','2018-04-30 23:10:12','Alert','You are alerted for some Reason','NO_03','Some Reason 1');
```

I need the List of Sources with the Latest Alert Received, Number of Alerts received in Last 24 hours and the Notified Version that sent the Last alert.

The Columns i need in my Result are,

1. source- Distinct Instances in the Table
2. notification_reason  - The Last Notification Raised, event if it is before 24 Hours for the source
3. notifier_version - The Notfier version which caused the last alert for the source
4. alert_count - Number of Alerts in Last 24 Hors for the source.

I tried something as it is in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14bb6a/2/0). Can someone correct me andd give solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the derived table idea to get the most recent ID and count for the last 24 hours.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(`notification_id`) AS AlertCount,
  MAX(`notification_id`) AS MaxNotification
FROM
  `notifications`
WHERE
  `created_time` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND NOW()
  AND `not_type` = 'Alert';
```

Then, join and filter on that:

```
SELECT
  NotificationTbl.source,
  NotificationTbl.notification_reason,
  NotificationTbl.notifier_version,
  Last24HoursTbl.alert_count
FROM
  `notifications` AS NotificationTbl
INNER JOIN
  (
   SELECT
      COUNT(`notification_id`) AS alert_count,
      MAX(`notification_id`) AS max_notification_id
    FROM
      `notifications`
    WHERE
      `created_time` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND NOW() 
      AND `not_type` = 'Alert'
  ) AS Last24HoursTbl
  ON NotificationTbl.notification_id = Last24HoursTbl.max_notification_id
  ;
```

Results (as of answer time):

```
source |    notification_reason | notifier_version | alert_count
------------------------------------------------------------
Europe |    Some Reason 1       | NO_03            | 1
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14bb6a/14

Comment: The Columns i need in my Result are,

    source- Distinct Instances in the Table
    notification_reason - The Last Notification Raised, event if it is before 24 Hours for the source
    notifier_version - The Notfier version which caused the last alert for the source
    alert_count - Number of Alerts in Last 24 Hors for the source.

Can you correct the query bit more

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select n.source,
       max(case when na.max_ni = n.notification_id then notification_reason end) as last_alert_reason,
       sum(n.not_type = 'Alert') as alert_count,
       max(case when na.max_ni = n.notification_id then notifier_version end) as last_alert_version 
from notifications n left join
     (select n2.source, max(notification_id) as max_ni
      from notifications n2
      where n2.not_type = 'Alert'
      group by n2.source
     ) na
     on n.source = na.source
group by n.source;
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14bb6a/9).